# use of constant in cuda is not accessed in the kernel

Tags: cuda

in the cuda code ,I am trying to use a structure and constant structure object and the value is assigned to constant object using cudaMemcpyToSymbol but this constant values are not accessed . I know the actual use of constant is not this way as each thread needs to access different values and cannot take advantage of memory broadcast to half warp but here in some situation I need this way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

using namespace std;

struct CDistance
{
    int Magnitude;
    int Direction;
};

__constant__ CDistance *c_daSTLDistance;
__global__ static void  CalcSTLDistance_Kernel(CDistance *m_daSTLDistance)
{
    int ID =  threadIdx.x;
    m_daSTLDistance[ID].Magnitude = m_daSTLDistance[ID].Magnitude + c_daSTLDistance[ID].Magnitude ;
    m_daSTLDistance[ID].Direction = 2 ;



} 




// main routine that executes on the host
int main(void)
{
  CDistance *m_haSTLDistance,*m_daSTLDistance;


  m_haSTLDistance = new CDistance[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
      m_haSTLDistance[i].Magnitude=3;
m_haSTLDistance[i].Direction=2;
  }
   //m_haSTLDistance =(CDistance*)malloc(100 * sizeof(CDistance));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&m_daSTLDistance,sizeof(CDistance)*10);
  cudaMemcpy(m_daSTLDistance,   m_haSTLDistance,sizeof(CDistance)*10, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpyToSymbol(c_daSTLDistance, m_haSTLDistance, sizeof(m_daSTLDistance)*10);
  CalcSTLDistance_Kernel<<< 1, 100 >>> (m_daSTLDistance);


  cudaMemcpy(m_haSTLDistance,   m_daSTLDistance, sizeof(CDistance)*10, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
      cout<<m_haSTLDistance[i].Magnitude<<endl;
  }


  free(m_haSTLDistance); 
  cudaFree(m_daSTLDistance);
}
```

here in the output, the constant c_daSTLDistance[ID].Magnitude is not accessed in the kernel and the statically assigned value 3 is obtained whereas I want this device value 3 is added to constant value and total 6 is returned.

while looking in to the cuda-memcheck it says error in read operation with memory out of bound

Comment: Why is `c_daSTLDistance` declared as a pointer? Do you understand the difference between a pointer and an array?

Comment: can't we just used pointer here in this example. Actually I am working on a simulation solver which consists of pointer as in the above code. yes I have tried the same with the use of array and yes it runs fine but here to match the solver code and see the result I am trying to make a pointer.

Comment: Self-evidently not. I think you need to do some revision on the concept of pointers in C++.

Comment: host and device pointers can be declared as CDistance *m_haSTLDistance,*m_daSTLDistance; and can be accessed then why not the constant pointers?? isn't is the same??

Comment: No it isn't the same. Ask yourself two questions (a) "did I initialise my constant memory pointer?" and (b) "can I dynamically allocate constant memory and assign the address of that allocation to a constant memory pointer?"

Comment: here I suppose we need to assign the address to the pointer at the beginning or assign the memory size. can't I assign null to the constant pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because of an uninitialised pointer/buffer overflow problem around the use of `c_daSTLDistance`. It is illegal to do this:

```
__constant__ CDistance *c_daSTLDistance;

....

cudaMemcpyToSymbol(c_daSTLDistance, m_haSTLDistance, sizeof(m_daSTLDistance)*10);
```

No memory was every allocated or a valid value set for `c_daSTLDistance`.

Further, note that all constant memory variables must be statically defined, and there is no ability to dynamically allocate constant memory at runtime. Therefore, what you are attempting to do can't be made to work. Also note that on all but the very oldest of CUDA devices, kernel arguments are stored in constant memory. So if you had a trivially small array of constant structures, it would be far easier and simpler to pass them by value to the kernel. The compiler and runtime will automagically place them in constant memory for you without any explicit host API calls.